# How can I get my "Notebook PC" to follow links it should, and not auto-click on rogue links?

Tags: windows-10, links, asus-laptop, advertisements

I bought an ASUS awhile back; it's perhaps the worst purchase I've ever made (if I ignore the bottle of Saki that smelled like dirty socks, that is) - so sue me, Asus!

I call it an "ad machine." Everywhere I click (on the scroll bar, mostly) it brings up pages advertising this or that (not just popups, but entire pages in separate browser instances).

Worse yet, perhaps, lately it has taken to NOT following legitimate links; I'll open a page, click on one of its links, and it won't go to it. I have to F5 the page to get the "linkiness" of the link back.

The machine was cheap; perhaps I should have known better ("you get what you pay for").

I am running "Windows 10 Home" and these are some details about the machine:

```
Manufacturer: ASUSTek Computer INc.
Model: X555LAB
Processor: Intel Core i3-5020U CPU @ 2.20GHz 2.20 GHz
RAM: 4.00 GB
System type: 64-bit OS, x64-based processor
```

Besides being a "buyer beware" I would also like to know if there is something I can do to turn off the rogue link clicking as well as muting of "real" links - some setting I can toggle or such?

Comment: I would just download Windows 10 Home ISO, format the machine, then not install any ASUS software. What browser?

Comment: Sounds like you've got an adware infection or similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: It sounds like you bought a used computer that the previous owner returned because they got it infected.

Comment: @Ramhound: I use Chrome most of the time, but Edge sometimes, too.

Comment: @cybernard: No, I bought it through amazon - not used.

Comment: So do my suggestion, nuke from orbit, guaranteed solution

Comment: @B.ClayShannon   People return stuff to amazon,or one of their many vendors, all the time.  Then amazon or their sub vendor resells it.  Especially, if they bought it, and returned it within 30 days or whatever the limit is.  To avoid detection, the customer could just say I need to trade it in for one with more <whatever>.